# How to use cursor loader to retrieve data using Retrofit?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, retrofit2, baseadapter, android-cursorloader

i successfully retrieve data from server using **Retrofit**, i want to use cursor loader in that for refresh to list.
i have used **BaseAdapter**.
can anybody tell me how to use cursorloader in retrofit

Comment: CursorLoader is for accessing data from ContentProvider ... it will obviously not help "for refresh to list"(what ever it means) when you are not working with ContentProvider

Comment: i have a list from database and if any value insert into table then it will automatic add into list

Comment: what database? local? then if you wana  use CursorLoader you should build own ContentProvider ... I do not see the point of using Retrofit with ContentProvider as it's doesn't need Model (as it's return Cursor which is more like Iterator with Map) ...  so parsing data to some Model(as Retrofit does) and then to Cursor would take unnecessary CPU cycles and memory

Comment: no, data getting from localhost server. so what should i use for it?
if it possible in content provider to get data from localhost server?

Comment: @Selvin can you please tell me how to perform this task?

Comment: @Selvin not concept clear first i want to store server data to sqlite and then use cursor loader for local database :) thnxs